# Validating XML that is a DOM document

Tags: java, xml, validation, schema, in-memory

How do I validate an XML document that I already have in memory as a DOM Document?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`javax.xml.validation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) APIs to validate XML in memory.  Below is an example of using these APIs with a `JAXBSource`, to validate a DOM model simply use a `DOMSource`.

```
package blog.validation;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Jane Doe");
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, customer);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("customer.xsd"));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        validator.validate(source);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

How do you made up your model? I have a solution at work where i get an XML message in text format which i parse using [xmlbeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Then i have the ability to call a validate method on it. So there is a Java class compiled during my maven build which reflects the XSD i have.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about it. The `javax.xml.validation` validators [take](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#validate%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29) a [`Source`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html). Check the constructors of the implementing classes of `Source`.